# Find coordinates of points given their distances

Tags: python, numpy

I have to find in Python the coordinates of the points A, B, C, D given their distances and the gradient of the line L (the one that passes through the center), which is parallel to segments AD and BC and orthogonal to segments AB and CD.

[image]

That is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np

# Gradient of the known line
l_gradient = 0.17
l_angle = np.arctan(l_gradient)

# Length of the segments
ad_distance =  1
ab_distance =  2

# Gradient and Intercept of lines AB and DC with the y axes 
ab_gradient = dc_gradient = -1 / l_gradient # orthogonal to L
dc_intercept = (ad_distance / 2) / np.sin(l_angle) # Inverse formula of the right triangle
ab_intercept = - dc_intercept

# Gradient and Intercept of lines AD and BC with the y axes 
ad_gradient = bc_gradient = l_gradient # parallel to L
ad_intercept = (ab_distance / 2) / np.cos(l_angle) # Inverse formula of the right triangle
bc_intercept = - ad_intercept
```

Comment: what did you try? What didn't work and what was the error?

Comment: I am trying to use as information the distance between the points and the angular coefficient of the line L, applying the trigonometric theorem of the right triangle, but with poor results.

Comment: post even the poor results and attempts you are making. It will make it easier for someone to help you

Comment: Are `AD` and `AB` equal? (In general, here obviously yes)

Comment: @mozway no in general they are different

Comment: Is your rectangular centrered around the origin and just rotated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is first assume the gradient is 0. Then we have our points:

```
ad_distance = 1
ab_distance = 2
points = np.array([
    [-ad_distance / 2, +ab_distance / 2],  # A
    [-ad_distance / 2, -ab_distance / 2],  # B
    [+ad_distance / 2, -ab_distance / 2],  # C
    [+ad_distance / 2, +ab_distance / 2],  # D
])
```

Note that at the bottom we have a triangle with sides `(x, l_gradient x, sqrt(1 + l_gradient^2) x)`. And remember `cos(angle) = adjacent / hypot`.

Thus we have:

```
l_gradient = 0.17
l_cos = 1 / np.sqrt(1 + l_gradient**2)
l_sin = l_gradient * l_cos
```

Now we can use those to construct a rotation matrix, and rotate our points into the correct positions:

```
l_rot = np.array([[l_cos , -l_sin], [l_sin, l_cos]])
points = (l_rot @ points.T).T
```

No trigonometry functions required!

Comment: This is the exact answer I would have given had the OP confirmed his rectangular is centered around the origin. If it is not, he requires the additional piece of info of the coords of said center, so you can shift `points` as calculated above.